# A Paragraph's Icon Using a Character

Tags: css, icons, font-face

I need to set an icon for some type of paragraphs like a note or a warning message.
I use @font-face rule and :before pseudo element to use characters as icons, like this:

```
p.warning:before    {content: '⚠';}
```

The problem is: how to present/style this icon the right way in the paragraph.
I mean in the top of the left/beginning margin?
As a solution I used these rules:

```
p.warning   {display: table;}
p.warning:before    {display: table-cell;}
```

It works fine in WebKit and Gecko, but not opera. Here's the output:

http://richstyle.org/demo-web.php

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the actual character itself, you need to put it's unicode character code in the `content` property, like this:

```
p.warning:before { 
    content: "\26A0";
}
```

The code for the symbol you gave was found [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/26a0/index.htm). Do note that some fonts may not support extended unicode characters. For example, doing a [quick test on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QL9m2/) with Chrome on Windows 7 yields a blank rectangle (character not supported). You might want to consider using an image with `background-image: url(...)` instead, or another character.

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't have such a problem.
The question is: how to display this icon the right way?

Comment: `:before` should display the character to the left on the first line of the paragraph. What exactly isn't working?